# Passing nullable parameters to a Page via PageParameters in Wicket 6

Tags: java, wicket, guava, wicket-1.6

I need to pass a parameter to my page and I can't find a way to pass parameters that might be null.

If I do:

```
PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters ();
pageParameters.add ("key", null);
```

This will result in an exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 'value' may not be null.
>        at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Args.notNull(Args.java:41)

If I use Google Guava's Optional, I can't find any way to cast the object even if the the Optional object is not holding a null ie not equals to Optional.absent() :

In my landing page's constructor I do

```
StringValue sv = parameters.get ("key");
sv.to ( Optional.of (MyEnum.SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT).getClass () );
```

and when I run it I get this error:

> org.apache.wicket.util.string.StringValueConversionException: Cannot
>   convert 'Optional.of(SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT)'to type class
>   com.google.common.base.Present.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there any other way to pass a possibly null object in wicket 6?

I noticed in wicket 1.4 they have  PageParameters.NULL which seems to have dissapeared in wicket 6.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just omit the parameter if its null and check if it is present in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be too simple, but what's wrong with

```
Object value = ?
if (value != null) {
    pageParameters.add ("key", value);
}
```

and

```
StringValue sv = pageParameters.get("key");
if (!sv.isNull()) {
    // process string value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All page parameters in wicket will be treated as Strings eventually. The idea is that a page parameter will be on the URL of the request.

From the javadoc:

> Suppose we mounted a page on `/user` and the following url was accessed `/user/profile/bob?action=view&redirect=false`. In this example `profile` and `bob` are indexed parameters with respective indexes `0` and `1`. `action` and `redirect` are named parameters.

If you add something like `x=y&x`, the parameter `x` will appear twice, once with the String `y` and another with the empty string.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish I would suggest to either

- Don't pass the parameter at all when there is a `null` value required and use the `isNull` or `toOptional` methods.
- Use indexed parameters and test for presence of a certain word